# Drupal Commons add a view handler to display all subgroup content of a group entity

Tags: views, 7

I've search a lot about how to add a view handler to display all subgroup content of a group entity ([og_group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module) for Drupal Commons 7.x-3.30. But with the answers that i've found sincerely i couldn't accomplish nothing... i.e. this https://www.drupal.org/node/1997988 Other suggestions? Thanks a lot for your precious help

Comment: I've found this article in drupal garden that seems to go to the right way... but it speaks about og_subgroup module that is unnecessary in commons 7.x-3.30. Is there any way to change this code to create a subgroup view in commons_groups module? (http://mohitaghera.drupalgardens.com/content/views-displaying-subgroup-current-group#comment-5296)